# Improve performance between calculating the distance between two points

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have this formula code to calculate the distance between two points - but its got performance issues.

```
  const pharmacy = await knex('place_of_interest')
    .select(
      knex.raw(
        `id, title, line1, line2, county, city, postcode, 
        (
          6371 * acos (
            cos ( radians(:lat:) )
            * cos( radians( ST_X(coordinate) ) )
            * cos( radians( ST_Y(coordinate) ) - radians(:lng:) )
            + sin ( radians(:lat:) )
            * sin( radians( ST_X(coordinate) ) )
          )
        ) AS distance`, latLng,
      ),
    )
    .andWhere('stock', '>', 0)
    .orderBy('distance')
```

if I add a limit - I do notice an improvement but then the results may be inaccurate. I am not sure if there is a way of using varnish to cache results - do a brute force on the calls - for the first fragment of postcodes?

Answer (score 1):

How about using https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html ? It should do the distance calculation as fast as possible.

However if you have huge amount of places whose distance is used to order results you may want to first add limit that results should not include those places which are too far away.

If even that is not performant enough places might need to be organized to clusters and then one should first select only those clusters that are near enough to be included and then order places according to exact distance.